# UISplitViewController not calling view delegate method in ios 5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I noticed this symptom in iOS 5 - Create an UISplitViewController with ViewController 1 on the left and ViewController 2 on the right. Open the popovercontroller in portrait, then close the popovercontroller. Viewcontroller 1's viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear methods does not get call. But in iOS 4.3 viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear methods does get call.

Anyone aware of a explanation for this change in behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers method of the UISplitViewController is set to return NO instead of YES. So subclassing UISplitViewController and overriding automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers to return YES solved the problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with the unmodified split view controller template (master-detail app, iPad only, no storyboard) and I can't confirm your observation. The appear/disappear callbacks are called, for both children of the split view controller.

So there must be something else happening in your app; our initial conditions are clearly not the same, somehow... Or we might not be talking about exactly the same callbacks at the same moments. There is a clear note in the documentation ("Message Forwarding to Its Child View Controllers") about how a split view controller forwards these callback messages.

Comment: Were appear/disappear delegate methods called after the popover dismisses in portrait mode?